# Breeze EFContextProvider ignores validation data annotation attributes

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm facing a problem to return the data annotation validation attributes viaw the metadata to the server .
Here is my class :

```
public class User
{
     public string Name { get; set; } 
     public string Company { get; set; } 
}
```

I added a metadata class to the User so I can configure the validation attributes there :

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata))]
    public partial class User
    {
        internal sealed class Metadata
        {
            private Metadata()
            {
            }
        }
      [Required]
      [MinLength(10)]
      .
      .
      .
      public string Company { get; set; } 
     }
```

I can't't see this validation in the client side when inspecting the entity.entityAspect , I tried to see in the DocCode the metadata result and I see these attributes really appear there , but in my model I don't see this attributes exposed to the client via the metadata.

Is there any extra configuration should do to get this, or any other issue may I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that the `MetadataTypeAttribute` on a "buddy class" is not respected by the Entity Framework EDM to which Breeze turns for its metadata. It appears that only data annotation attributes on the class itself are detected and even then only certain of them make it into the metadata.

> I'd be pleased to learn that I'm wrong about this.

We have it on our backlog to extend the ability of Breeze .NET components to pickup custom data annotations and it would be natural for such a facility to pickup attributes in the metadata buddy class. I cannot say when we'll get to this feature. I do not think it will be soon.

You might consider writing your own component to reflect over the classes, find these annotations, and build your own simple structure representing this supplementary metadata. Then you expose this from a custom Web API endpoint.  Then your client boostrapping can hit that endpoint, read the supplementary metadata and update the client metadata with the pertinent validations. Yes you can add validations anytime after the primary metadata have been loaded in a `MetadataStore`.

Wish I could come up with something better or had something in my bag.

> If you write this component, please let us and the community know. We'd love to offer it in Breeze Labs. Full credit and gratitude of course.

Comment: Thanks allot , I'll try to figure out this solution and let you know on it .

Comment: Actually I choosed to implement this with T4 , I reflected over the Metadata and generated a script corresponding to the breeze validator.  Actually I found breeze suggests much more validators that the metadata attributes , so don't know if this so efficient . Any way , I can share the T4 template with its first drop .

Comment: Cool. We're watching and eager to know how you feel about the tradeoffs when you've lived with it a bit.

Comment: Actuallly I procced with the T4 , and I think it will be extremly cool if breeze.net can bundle all the suggested client side validators with .net metadata attributes , so we can have :
1. same attributes structure corresponding to the client side validators.
2. We can control the error messages also by the attribute definision.
I think it will be end to end support for validation. I really can help contribute this but need your help how to integrate with breeze.net structure.

Comment: @Wasim - can you please put your t4 template up as an answer or in a link - I have encountered the same problem, and would love not to have to write the same code (I am also positive others will also encounter this problem)